# Individual objects from Array are showing on NSLog with NSString but when addObject: to NSMutableArray, Array is null?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

**THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES**

```
NSString *individualEventTitle;
NSMutableArray *eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSUInteger index =0; (index < 8) ; index++){

    EventsList *eventList = [[EventsList alloc] initWithIndex:index];

    NSString *individualEventTitle = eventList.eventTitle;
    /*self.eventTitleArray = eventList.eventTitle;
    self.eventLocationArray = eventList.eventLocation;
    self.eventIconArray = eventList.eventIcon;
    self.eventPriceArray = eventList.eventPrice;
    self.eventTypeArray = eventList.eventType;*/

    [eventTitleArray addObject:individualEventTitle];
    NSLog(@"Title of Event:%@", individualEventTitle);
    NSLog(@"Array of Event:%@", eventTitleArray);
}
```

So from my understanding, the loop should go through itself 8 times (to account for the number of items in my class array). To confirm this I NSLogged a string for the eventList.eventTitle and assigned it to a string called individualEventTitle. Upon reading the console I received ALL 8 event Titles.

However, when I add the command at the end of the loop, to add that string to the NSMutableArray *eventTitleArray. It appears null in the console when NSlogged.

I would highly appreciate some help, as I've spend the last two nights just tinkering with it with no avail!

Thank you!

**Contents of my console**

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlXTG.png)

Comment: Please only post a minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I apologise. I just wanted to include all the backend code relative to where the problem lies. Incase the backend of the method I am trying to implement actually has problematic code.

Comment: I hope this is better, do you have any insight to my problem?

Comment: What appears as null? `eventTitleArray` or `individualEventTitle`?

Comment: eventTitleArray appears as null. However when I log the individualEventTitle I get the object I desire

Comment: In the code you posted, `eventTitleArray` can't be `nil` since you alloc/init on the 2nd line you posted.

Comment: That's why I am confused. I have attached an image of my console, on the main question body, showing the two logs one for the 'individualEventTitle' and 'eventTitleArray'.

Comment: So I have logged to see how many items are in my Array, which is 8 - as intended. Although it says I have 8 items, when I try to actually NSLog the contents itself I just receive "(".

Comment: Is this in any way related to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135501/nsarray-has-objects-yet-uicollectionview-is-appearing-empty/45135637?noredirect=1#comment77240645_45135637 ?

Comment: Yes Tcharni, thank you so much - it's all working accordingly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

```
[eventTitleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",individualEventTitle]];
```