# NSArray has objects yet UICollectionView is appearing empty

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I've been working on this project to expand my portfolio. I am still rather new to objective-c, so help would be highly appreciated!

I have been tinkering with this code for a few days now. I am aware the labels work, as I was able to get all the cells to display the same information (not the desired result). This was likely to a fault where my array didn't store all the objects.

Below is the code for my UIViewController;

**INITIAL PROBLEM**

So I have confirmed that the NSLog, displays 8 objects which is what I aiming for.

```
@interface YourDowey ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventTitleArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventLocationArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventIconArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventPriceArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventTypeArray;


@end

@implementation YourDowey

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventIconArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; (index < 8) ; index++){

    EventsList *eventList = [[EventsList alloc] initWithIndex:index];

    NSString *individualEventTitle = eventList.eventTitle;
    NSString *individualEventLocation = eventList.eventLocation;

    NSString *individualEventIcon = eventList.eventIcon;
    NSString *individualEventPrice = eventList.eventPrice;
    NSString *individualEventType = eventList.eventType;

    [eventTitleArray addObject:individualEventTitle];
    [eventLocationArray addObject:individualEventLocation];
    [eventIconArray addObject:individualEventIcon];
    [eventPriceArray addObject:individualEventPrice];
    [eventTypeArray addObject:individualEventType];

    }
NSLog(@"Events: %@", eventTitleArray);
NSLog(@"Number of objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[eventTitleArray count]);
}
```

However, when I use the method for deciding how many cells I want, through the array count I achieve 0 cells on the UICollectionView? Which is confusing as the NSLog confirms that there are 8 objects.

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.eventTitleArray count];
}
```

This is the code relative to the UIViewControllerCell and assigning the arrays to the cells respective UIObject (label/image).

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
EventsCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eventsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *imagesString = [self.eventIconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagesString];
cell.eventTitle.text = [self.eventTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventLocation.text = [self.eventLocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventPrice.text = [self.eventPriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventType.text = [self.eventTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

**My Suspicions**

I'm trying to sense the logic behind the problem. And I'm not sure if it goes down to the fact the UICollectionView methods are called before the viewDidLoad? I mean in the viewDidLoad the array evidently through NSLog has 8 objects in it, yet when tinkering with the methods relative to the UICollectionView/Cells they seem to be empty??

**UPDATED**

Below is the code which relates to the dictionary from which the Array is getting assigned information to;

**EventsLibrary.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString *const kTitle;
extern NSString *const kLocation;
extern NSString *const kPrice;
extern NSString *const kIcon;
extern NSString *const kLargeIcon;
extern NSString *const kType;

@interface EventsLibrary : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *library;

@end
```

**EventsLibrary.m**

```
#import "EventsLibrary.h"

NSString *const kTitle = @"title";
NSString *const kLocation = @"location";
NSString *const kPrice = @"price";
NSString *const kIcon = @"icon";
NSString *const kLargeIcon = @"largeIcon";
NSString *const kType = @"type";

@implementation EventsLibrary

-(instancetype) init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _library        =   @[      @{   kTitle:@"iCafe de Paris",
                                     kLocation:@"International Drive",
                                     kPrice:@"$10",
                                     kIcon:@"iCafe.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"iCafeLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Food"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Orlando's Museum of Art",
                                     kLocation:@"N Mills Ave",
                                     kPrice:@"$20",
                                     kIcon:@"Museum.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"MuseumLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Art"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Club 180",
                                     kLocation:@"W Church Street",
                                     kPrice:@"$20",
                                     kIcon:@"Club180.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"Club180Lrg.png",
                                     kType:@"NightLife"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Wekiva Springs",
                                     kLocation:@"Wekiva Circle, Apopka",
                                     kPrice:@"$5",
                                     kIcon:@"Wekiva.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"WekivaLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Nature"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Kings Bowling",
                                     kLocation:@"International Drive",
                                     kPrice:@"$10",
                                     kIcon:@"Kings.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"KingLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Sports"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Pirate's Cove Mini Golf",
                                     kLocation:@"International Drive",
                                     kPrice:@"$15",
                                     kIcon:@"PiratesGolf.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"PiratesGolfLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Sports"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Cobb's Plaza Cinema",
                                     kLocation:@"S Orange Ave",
                                     kPrice:@"$8",
                                     kIcon:@"Cobbs.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"CobbsLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Art"},

                                @{   kTitle:@"Mango's Cafe",
                                     kLocation:@"International Drive",
                                     kPrice:@"FREE",
                                     kIcon:@"Mangos.png",
                                     kLargeIcon:@"MangosLrg.png",
                                     kType:@"Food"}
                          ];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

**EventsList.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EventsLibrary.h"

@interface EventsList : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventIcon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventIconLarge;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *eventType;

- (instancetype)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

**EventsList.m**

```
#import "EventsList.h"

@implementation EventsList

-(instancetype)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    EventsLibrary *eventsLibrary = [[EventsLibrary alloc]init];
    NSArray *library = eventsLibrary.library;

    NSDictionary *eventsDictionary = library[index];

    _eventTitle = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kTitle];
    _eventLocation = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kLocation];
    _eventPrice = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kPrice];

    NSString *iconName = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kIcon];
    _eventIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:iconName];

    NSString *largeIconName = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kLargeIcon];
    _eventIconLarge = [UIImage imageNamed:largeIconName];

    _eventType = [eventsDictionary objectForKey:kType];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where's your code that populates `self.eventTitleArray`? The code you posted populates another, local, array variable with a similar name.

Comment: Why do you have 5 separate arrays? Why not just one array of event objects?

Comment: Agree with @rmaddy. Consider using one array populated with NSDictionary objects, each of which contain ImageName, Title, Location, Price and Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out your problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventIconArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
NSMutableArray *eventTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
...
}
```

Note that you are re-declaring all the variables again in your `viewDidLoad` function. This hides your properties, and hence they are never really initialised. Once you declare them in your class definition, you can use `self.eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init...]` instead.

I would suggest something like:

```
NSMutableArray *eventArray; //One single array for all

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.eventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; (index < 8) ; index++){

    EventsList *eventList = [[EventsList alloc] initWithIndex:index];

    NSString *individualEventTitle = eventList.eventTitle;
    NSString *individualEventLocation = eventList.eventLocation;

    NSString *individualEventIcon = eventList.eventIcon;
    NSString *individualEventPrice = eventList.eventPrice;
    NSString *individualEventType = eventList.eventType;

    NSDictionary *eventDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: eventList.eventTitle, @"Title", eventList.eventLocation, @"Location", eventList.eventIcon, @"Icon", eventList.eventPrice, @"Price, eventList.eventType, @"Type", nil];

    [eventArray addObject:eventDictionary];

    }
NSLog(@"Events: %@", eventArray);
NSLog(@"Number of objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[eventArray count]);
}
```

You could then use `[NSDictionary objectForKey:@""]` to access the required data point at a future time. It also means, you only have to manage one array that has all your information. Qualitatively, it will not affect your program logic at all

Comment: So in your viewDidLoad function: eventTitleArray and self.eventTitleArray are two different variables, hence the problem

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much!! You're a genius! Such a simple solution! Thank you! Thank you! THANK YOU!

Comment: I've made the same mistake numerous times. You just begin to watch out for it beyond a point.